# set delegate and dataSource to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, static-methods

How I can set delegate and dataSource **inside a static method**.

```
+(void)method
{
    UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tv.delegate = self;   // Warning: incompatible pointer type
    tv.dataSource = self; // Warning: incompatible pointer type
}
```

Comment: You can't unless you pass the delegate/datasource *to* the class method.

Comment: While the question can be answered (there are ways), I do not understand why you are using a class method to do this.  I think it indicates bigger architectural problems with your app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possiblities,

One: If this is a singleton class (assuming the singleton implements both datasource and delegate methods)

```
+(void)method
{
    UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tv.delegate = [SingletonClass sharedInstance]; // This will return the singleton instance
    tv.dataSource = [SingletonClass sharedInstance]; // This will return the singleton instance
}
```

Two: If not a singleton class, modify the method signature to accept the delegate and datasource instance

```
+(void)methodWithDelegate:(id)delegate andDatasource:(id)datasource
{
    UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tv.delegate = delegate;
    tv.dataSource = datasource;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SingletonClass View controller class declared like this ?

```
@interface SingletonClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

However, what you do seems like a bad design